# Can I make a share button for facebook and link it with a specific div to share?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I have a website on WordPress, I do have infoboxes created and would like to give a share button down below each box and link it with the box to share only the contents of the box instead of the whole page. Each div has it's own ID defined however there is no predefined link for each of them.

Any way, I can create a share button and link this infobox with it using the ID to share? I want to make these boxes shareable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In facebook documentation to create a share link button it says

> Pick the URL of a website or Facebook Page you want to share.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/?locale=en_US

So if you want to share something you must have a link to share.

You can create a specific page about your infoboxes and share the link of your-website/the-infobox.

If you manage to make a link your code for the share button will look like this

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&layout=button_count&size=small&width=96&height=20&appId" width="96" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

Or

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v10.0" nonce="qXOmpYBu"></script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution! I got the idea, will work on it and definitely update you here :)